# jQuery method that disallows input of certain chars

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to make a jQuery method that would delete wanted chars from selected elements.

For example:

```
$("input").disallowChars(/\D/g);// should disallow input of all non-digit elements in input elements
```

This is how I thought to do it, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$.fn.disallowChars = function(regexp){
  this.keyup(function(){

    var value = $(this).val();
    value.replace(regexp, "");
    $(this).val(value);

  });
  return this;
};

$("input").disallowChars(/\D/g);
```

I'm a total newbie at this, how can I make it work.

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell what kind of characters you don't want??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `String.fromCharCode()` and `keypress` event instead:

```
$.fn.disallowChars = function(regexp){
  return this.keypress(function(e){
      if(String.fromCharCode(e.which).match(regexp)) return false;
  });
};
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z3tjryg2/)

**BUT** doesn't disable any characters to be paste in input using mouse or paste keyboard shortcut.

On modern browsers, you could use `input` event, or `change keyup paste mouseup` (ya mouseup, to handle dropped text too):

```
$.fn.disallowChars = function(regexp){
  return this.on('input', function(){
      this.value = this.value.replace(regexp, '');          
  });
};
```

**BUT** then once input value is replaced, text carret is put in end (or start depending browser behaviour) of string input.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z3tjryg2/1/)

Answer (score 1):

heres a handy routine I use to sanitize some input fields in a current project:

```
// REPLACE SELECTOR WITH YOUR ID(S) OR SELECTORS...
$('input').bind("change keyup", function() {  
 var val = $.trim($(this).val());
    // READ UP ON REGEX TO UNDERSTAND WHATS GOING ON HERE... ADD CHARACTERS YOU WANT TO ELIMINATE...
    var regex = /[":'/\+;<>&\\/\n]/g;
 if (val.match(regex)) {
   val = val.replace(regex, "");
   $(this).val($.trim(val));
 }
});
```

Heres another version I used recently:

```
$("#myField").on("keypress", function(event) {
// THIS ONLY ALLOWS A-Z, A-Z, 0-9 AND THE @ SYMBOL... just change stuffToAllow to suit your needs
var stuffToAllow = /[A-Za-z0-9@ ]/g;
var key = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
if (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39 || stuffToAllow.test(key)) {
    return true;
}
alert( key + ' character not allowed!');
return false;
```

});

Comment: I was thinking of making a jQuery method that accepts parameter which would be regexp. In that way I could simply define which characters I want to have and which not. The method would be somehow universal I guess.

Comment: If I need to leave only numbers in some inputs, and in others only letters, I would simply put different regexp as a parameter.

Comment: @atho - ahhh, I did that recently, i'll see if I can find the code for it.

Comment: i would be very grateful if you can :)

Comment: @atho - not QUITE what you're after (see updated answer above) ... I recall running into problem converting the variable I was trying to pass to regexp and also issues with detecting the event for the key press... I gave up on it and just settled for the 2nd version shown in my answer.  good luck.